# Can't close modals in VueJS2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I ran into strange behavior when trying to close my modals. I wrote methods to show and close modal

```
methods: {
showModal: function () {
  this.show = true;
  console.log(this.show);
},
closeModal: function () {
  this.show = false;
  console.log(this.show);
},
```

Modal should appear by clicking on the row of the table

```
<tr class="hover-hand" @click="showModal">

<div v-show="show" class="modal is-active">
```

I tried to render it with a separate components, but temporarily put everything in one If I try to open a modal everything is ok screenshot with modal https://pp.userapi.com/c638017/v638017273/39134/98lcFy5OWvc.jpg

But if I try to close i have some trouble screenshot with console output it logged console.log(this.show); twice with different params. Also modal does not close. https://pp.userapi.com/c638017/v638017273/39148/mIpSQMQYLNg.jpg

Sorry I don't know how to create simplified version of project at jsfiddle, pasted whole component code here

```js
<template>
  <tr class="hover-hand" @click="showModal">
    <td>{{ beer.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ beer.home }}</td>
    <td>{{ beer.sort }}</td>
    <td>{{ beer.density }}</td>
    <td>{{ beer.alcohol_content }}</td>
    <td>{{ beer.ibu }}</td>
    <td>
      <span class="icon">
        <i v-if="beer.on_tap === true" v-bind:style="{ color: activeColor }" class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </span>
    </td>
      <div v-show="show" class="modal is-active">
        <div class="modal-background"></div>
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-content">
              <p class="title">
              {{ beer.name }}
              </p>
              <p class="subtitle">
              Jeff Atwood
              </p>
            </div>
            <footer class="card-footer">
              <p class="card-footer-item">
              <span>
                  View on <a href="https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/506010907021828096">Twitter</a>
              </span>
              </p>
              <p class="card-footer-item">
              <span>
                  Share on <a href="#">Facebook</a>
              </span>
              </p>
            </footer>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button class="modal-close" @click="closeModal"></button>
      </div>
  </tr>
  
</template>

<script>
import SingleBeerModal from '@/components/Beerlist/SingleBeerModal';

export default {
  name: 'SingleBeer',
  data() {
    return {
      activeColor: 'green',
      show: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    showModal: function () {
      this.show = true;
      console.log(this.show);
    },
    closeModal: function () {
      this.show = false;
      console.log(this.show);
    },
  },
  components: {
    'beer-modal': SingleBeerModal,
  },
  props: ['beer'],
};

</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try `v-on:click.prevent="closeModal"` ?

Comment: I guess you are trying to place component into the table in standard way...https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#DOM-Template-Parsing-Caveats

Comment: @Pradeepb yes, it had no effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have a tr with a @click on top of everything, so when you click on the button

```
<button class="modal-close" @click="closeModal"></button>
```

this click is also being propagated to the main tr, so Pradeepb it almost had it, i think you should try

```
v-on:click.stop="closeModal"
```

This will cause click to stop propagating up to the tr, because right now is closing the modal and opening the modal at the same time.

Also, don't use click event on TR, try to reestructurate using divs, onclick events on TR can cause weird behaviour

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is what i need `v-on:click.stop="closeModal"` Also I will try to reorganize my code.